# Chrome OS New fonts

Tags: fonts, google-chrome-os

I've read that the [Chrome OS Core Fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croscore_fonts) were originally: Arimo (sans-serif), Tinos (serif) and Cousine (monospace) and that just recently Google replaced `Noto Sans` by `Roboto` as the default sans-serif font on the UI (guessing Noto Sans replaced Arimo at one point?).

I was wondering if anyone knew what is the current monospace font they use as it doesn't look like it is [Cousine](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cousine) anymore, it's feels more like [Ubuntu Mono](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu+Mono).

Any clues?

**EDIT**: By searching other systems and their monospaced font I came across [DejaVu SansMono](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans-mono) which when compared to the current Chrome OS monotype font seems like a match. I can't find any literature that could confirm it.

Comment: Where exactly are you referring to seeing this _new monospace font_? I have just looked at a web page text with _font-family: monospace_ using [the developer tools feature to see rendered font](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that?hl=en) and it is coming back as Cousine.

Comment: Maybe that's true for the browser. What I was testing specifically was the shell font.

Comment: If you are talking about the crosh tab accessible via _Ctrl-Alt-T_, then that is **DejaVu Sans Mono** in CrOS 45, according to DevTools as detailed in above link. I have no idea what the developer console (_Ctrl-Alt-F2/→_) is using, and 3rd party shell apps can use whatever they like.